# How to give a paint brush affect using bare finger with ARKit & SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine, scenekit, arkit

I am trying to build an app to draw graffiti in ARKit using bare hands.

The graffiti should look realistic. I have gone through many examples and I see most of us using SCNSphere. Well, It does do that job but there are gaps between each sphere that do not give a realistic touch.

1. How do we come up with a brush/drawn line effect?
2. Is scenekit the best way to do this or shall we try spritekit/Unity?

My basic code looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import ARKit
import SceneKit

class ViewController : UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, ARSessionDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sceneView.delegate = self as ARSCNViewDelegate
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGesture(_:))))
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        sceneView = ARSCNView(frame:CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.height, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width))
        sceneView.delegate = self
        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        config.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
        sceneView.session.delegate = self
        self.view = sceneView
        sceneView.session.run(config)
    }
    
    @objc func panGesture(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        gesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
        guard let query = sceneView.raycastQuery(from: gesture.location(in: gesture.view), allowing: .existingPlaneInfinite, alignment: .any) else {
            return
        }
        let results = sceneView.session.raycast(query)
        guard let hitTestResult = results.first else {
            return
        }
        let position = SCNVector3Make(hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x, hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y, hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
        let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 0.5)
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
        sphere.materials = [material]
        let sphereNode = SCNNode()
        sphereNode.scale = SCNVector3(x:0.004,y:0.004,z:0.004)
        sphereNode.geometry = sphere
        sphereNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y:0.02, z: -1)
        self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
        sphereNode.position = position
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I guess, your app produces a bunch of scene nodes during you make the pan gesture. This can result in a mess. The numer of draw calls will very quickly reach the limits, and overload graphics engine. In addition the result, is not homogenious - this is, I guess, what you call spaces. Is your goal to draw on a surface of a Scene Geometry object? I do not have a solution for you, but maybe here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26129111/scenekit-painting-on-texture-with-texture-coordinates?noredirect=1&lq=1) you will find some approach to make something in the direction of a AR graffiti app.

Comment: Thanks @ZAY

I am trying to draw on a SceneView. It. is supposed to be a simple drawing app that should let me draw on any horizontal/vertical object & retain when I change camera focus.