# Can i use pencil kit to draw on 3D models in scenekit Swift UI

Tags: ios, swiftui, scenekit, pencilkit

Ok, so i've been using apples swift for about 6-7 months now, my current group and I, were exploring a few ideas for our last project at the academy. my mind is completely hung on an app targeted around 3d design. Not modeling, essentially taking models and color/texturing them.

**Specific question**
Can i combine scene kit and pencil kit swift ui, in a way to create an app to color and texture blank 3d models?

Any ideas on where to start or how we should go about doing so.

Example:

1. uploads 3d model of a tree (Tree consists of 3 individual pieces(Tree, Leaves, Apple)
2. isolate desired part (Apple)
3. Select pencil/brush type, select color (Red)
4. Paint the Apple with the red pencil/brush
   Examples/Resources also appreciated

Comment: This could give you probably some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26129111/scenekit-painting-on-texture-with-texture-coordinates